# Não consigo salvar dados do formulário

Tags: php

pessoal nao estou conseguindo salvar os dados do meu formulário no banco.

tenho os seguintes arquivos:

functions.php

```
/**
 *  Cadastro de Notas
 */
function add() {
  if (!empty($_POST['nota'])) {

    $today = 
      date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
    $nota = $_POST['nota'];
    $aluno = $_POST['nota'];
    $nota['modified'] = $nota['created'] = $today->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    save('notas', $nota);
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}
```

add.php

```
<?php 
  require_once('functions.php'); 
  add();
  index2();
  ?>

<?php include(HEADER_TEMPLATE); ?>

<h2>Cadastrar Nota</h2>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
  <!-- area de campos do form -->
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Aluno</label>


      <select class="form-control">

      <?php if ($alunos) : ?>
      <?php foreach ($alunos as $aluno) : ?>  

      <option value="<?php echo $aluno['AlunoID']; ?>" name="nota['AlunoID']"><?php echo $aluno['AlunoNome']; ?></option>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else : ?>

      <option>SEM RESULTADOS</option>

      <?php endif; ?>

      </select>


    </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Materia</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['MateriaID']">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Nota</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['Nota']">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="campo3">Data de Cadastro</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['created']" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="actions" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
      <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<?php include(FOOTER_TEMPLATE); ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que pode ser?

qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

desde ja obrigado pela sua atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o seu formulário esteja com alguns erros.

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Aluno</label>

      <select class="form-control">
        <?php if ($alunos) : ?>
          <?php foreach ($alunos as $aluno) : ?>  
            <option value="<?php echo $aluno['AlunoID']; ?>" name="nota['AlunoID']"><?php echo $aluno['AlunoNome']; ?></option>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <option>SEM RESULTADOS</option>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Materia</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['MateriaID']">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <label for="name">Nota</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['Nota']">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="campo3">Data de Cadastro</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota['created']" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="actions" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
      <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

1. Seu elemento `select` não possui o atributo `name` definido. Ao invés disso, você definiu o atributo em `option`. Remova do `option` e defina-o em `select`:

   ```
   <select class="form-control" name="nota['AlunoID']">
      ...
   </select>
   ```
2. O campo `nota['created']` está como `disabled`, então seu valor não será enviado na submissão do formulário. Não chega a ser um erro, visto que na função você redefine este valor, mas não faz muito sentido possuir um campo vazio e desativado por padrão no formulário.

Dentro da função `add`, você pode comentar a linha `header` e colocar `var_dump($nota)` para verificar se os dados do formulário estão chegando como esperado.

Comment: Valeu Anderson! tinha definido o atributo name no lugar errado era no select mesmo. Valeu mesmo Brother!